# Scala classes - need to shrink memory use for Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory

I'm having problems with **memory** in **Spark** while using **Scala** classes to hold data.

I'm using some nested case classes to hold some data in an RDD.  One data run seems like it will amount to ~400 TB using the case classes I wrote.  That's way too big ($), and I'm a little confused about why it's taking up so much memory.

The average record is taking up around 2.7 kB.  This seems high.

The case classes (in aggregate) have about 77 fields.  Approximately...

- 23 String
- 17 Option[String]
- 16 Option[Int]
- 9 Option[Float]
- 5 Double
- 4 Long
- missing a few, but you get the general makeup

I guess that works out 35 Bytes per field, which seems long.  None of the Strings are egregiously long.

These classes (wrapped in one outer class) look generally like these

```
case class RawMeta(
    trigger: Option[String],
    triggerApp: Option[String],
    elSchema: Option[String],
    elClient: Option[String],
    eventDataSchema: Option[String],
    android: Option[String],
    strProcessDate: String,
    strProcessTime: String,
    strVersion: String)
```

and

```
case class RawLocation(
    lat: Double,
    lon: Double,
    locPrecision: Option[Float],
    altitude: Option[Int],
    altPrecision: Option[Int],
    locationAge: Option[Int],
    speed: Option[Float] = None,
    speedPrecision: Option[Float] = None,
    bearing: Option[Int] = None,
    bearingPrecision: Option[Int] = None)
```

A few have some simple methods or pattern matching.  The only extensive one looks basically like...

```
lazy val (field1, field2): (String, String) = _field0 match {
  case "xxx" => ("K" + _field1, _field2)
  case "yyy" => ("A" + _field1, _field2)
  case "zzz" => ("M" + _field1, _field2)
  // 17 more like this
}
```

If I can't throw away any fields, and I can't afford to work with 400 TB, what are my best options for shrinking the size of my data down?  What's going to gain me the most if anything?

- quit using `Option`s and use `""` or `Int.MinValue` or similar instead of `None`? (I hate this idea for anything other than String values)
- replace Strings that have limited (say < 100) possible values with case objects wrapping the String...  does it become a Singleton and only exist in memory once instead of having a String in every instance of data?
- replacing Strings that have limited possible values with an Int and then sticking a `Map[Int, String]` as a lookup in a companion object?

Any better ideas?  What buys me the most?  Any of these?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

re comment about how I know size

when I persist the RDD, I can only get about 1/2 of it to cache, and that takes up 2.2 TB for half of ~ 1/90th of my data.

[image: storage tab]

and Ganglia looks like this when I start a new spark session and read serialized data in from S3.  (i.e. after parsing into classes, I serialize using `.saveAsObjectFile` and then start over to clear out any memory from reading raw JSON in and parsing)

[image: ganglia]

again, it's only ever half cached and it's still slow to work with.

also...  oddly, when I serialize it, it has 2,664 partitions, and when I read it back in it has 45k partitions.  not sure why.

Comment: Where that 400TB comes from? Did you see it in a UI?

Comment: I have 3 datasets, and I need to pull in a month of all three to run a batch.  I'm developing on 1 day of 1 dataset and it's 4.3 TB (1.59 billion records) using Ganglia & storage tab in spark ui.  3 x 31 x 4.3 = ~400.  maybe it won't be exactly that, but 4.3 TB is way too big for ~1/90th of my data.

Comment: added screen grabs

Answer (score 1):

1. Definitely get rid of `Option`s. They introduce additional indirection in memory, especially when used with primitive types. Instead, you can use nullable values or an alternative to `Option` that is implemented as a value class ([here's](https://github.com/AVSystem/scala-commons/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/avsystem/commons/misc/Opt.scala) an example implementation).
2. To reduce the memory footprint of commonly encountered `String` values , you can try calling [`.intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()) on them before passing them into case classes. This is conceptually similar to your `Map[Int, String]` proposal, but supported directly and transparently by the JVM.